# Evaluating the integral: $\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(x\right)\ln ^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(x\right)}{x}\:dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers

I'd like to evaluate and find the closed form for
$$\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(x\right)\ln ^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(x\right)}{x}\:dx$$
But it's very difficult since its related to alternating harmonic series of weight 6.

To show so one can make use of $\frac{1}{4}\ln ^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(H_n-2H_{2n}\right)}{n}x^{2n}$ and obtain:
$$-2\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(H_n-2H_{2n}\right)}{n}\int _0^1x^{2n-1}\ln \left(x\right)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(x\right)\:dx$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{H_nH_{2n}}{n^4}}_{S_1}-\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{H_nH_{2n}^{\left(2\right)}}{n^3}}_{S_2}+\zeta \left(2\right)\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{H_n}{n^3}+\underbrace{\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{H_{2n}^2}{n^4}}_{S_3}+\underbrace{\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{H_{2n}H_{2n}^{\left(2\right)}}{n^3}}_{S_4}-2\zeta \left(2\right)\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{H_{2n}}{n^3}$$
From this it can be seen that some of the series like $S_1, S_2, S_3$ and $S_4$ are very difficult yet one can find relations involving them such as
$$5\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^nH_n}{n^5}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^nH_n^2}{n^4}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^nH_n^{\left(2\right)}}{n^4}=-\frac{175}{32}\zeta \left(6\right)+\frac{1}{2}\zeta ^2\left(3\right)$$
Yet it's still quite hard, I'd appreciate any insight, thanks.

Comment: The result is $$6\zeta(\bar{5},1)-\frac{7}{3} \pi ^2 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{39 \zeta (3)^2}{8}-\frac{49}{24} \pi ^2 \zeta (3) \log (2)+\frac{383 \pi ^6}{12096}-\frac{1}{72} 7 \pi ^2 \log ^4(2)+\frac{7}{72} \pi ^4 \log ^2(2)$$ with $\zeta(\bar{5},1) = \sum_{n=2} \frac{(-1)^n H_{n-1}}{n^5}$, this sum can be expressed in terms of $\text{Li}_6(-1/8)$ and $\text{Li}_6(-1/2)$, but the proof is highly nontrivial.

Comment: very interesting and odd at the same time, truly thought that the final closed form avoided such sum/mzv, thanks.

Comment: @pisco Is there a reference for this closed form of $\zeta(\bar5,1)$? Thanks

Comment: @EdwardH https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.04770